# Location of AppXPackage Data?

Tags: powershell, appxmanifest

Where is the data used by the PS cmdlets like "Get-AppXPackage" stored physically? I know each package has a manifest, but there must be a index of all packages.

Comment: I'm not really 100% sure what you're after. The main default AppX locations that I am aware of are `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`,`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages` and `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\appx`. `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers` will return a full list of all appx packages installed and their current status for each user (requires admin privileges)

Comment: I have been trying to use Remove-AppxPackage to delete an app under team development (that was locally deployed by a user that is no longer on the project), with no success. It remains in the results from Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers and blocks the attempts to deploy by the other team members. Hence I am trying to manually delete the pointer to the actual app package which Get-AppxPackage uses to produce the full list.

Comment: When you run `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers` does the application show as `Installed` or `Staged` for users that no longer have profiles or accounts on the workstation? If so, the only way I have found to remove these is to remove the WMI Objects left behind for that account - Run `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_UserProfile` to confirm whether that user shows, if so `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | ? { $_.SID -eq "S-1-5.." } | Remove-WMIObject` adding the relevant SID in place of `S-1-5..`

Comment: If you are on a newer build of W10, you also have the `-User` and `-AllUsers` parameter on `Remove-AppXPackage`. I forget which build this was introduce in.

Comment: IsPartiallyStaged  is False however there is no InstallLocation specified. I successfully removed the WMIObject for the user, but that didn't impact my ability to remove the AppxPackage using Remove-AppxPackage specifying the "-user" parameter. I receive either a "security ID structure" error or a "user was logged off" error.

Comment: So I think I am back to where is the information physically stored?